# Custom attributes and classes on Ember form elements?

Tags: ember.js

So we use CSS tooltips in our project which basically require adding the class "tooltip-extended" and adding the property `aria-label` to the HTML tag which contains the text of the tooltip. These are purely CSS tooltips and work everywhere. So on `link-to` helper it was pretty easy. However, I ran into an issue with form elements. Primarily because Ember seems to make the actual form elements `display: none` in some cases, like with checkboxes, and adds a sub-element `A` tag which is what is visible.

This is the code for the form stuff, pretty standard:

```
{{input 
  type="checkbox" 
  class="tv-checkbox" 
  checked=defaultSetup 
  data-label="Default Settings"
  name=defaults
  change=(action "toggleDefaults" value="target.checked")}}

{{#radio-button
  class="tooltip-enhanced"
  value="simple"
  name="complexity"
  groupValue=passphraseComplexity
  changed="complexityChanged"}}
  Simple
{{/radio-button}}
```

If I add `tooltip-extended` to the class it either doesn't add it at all, or it adds it to the actual form element which is `display: none`. Even extending the attributes allowed would not put these attributes on the child elements created.

It is desirable that the tooltip appear directly over the element the mouse is over. If the class and attribute are placed on a parent `DIV` element, this is not the behavior that ensues because it centers on the element.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: where is the source code for radio-button? what kind of a component are you using for actual form?

Comment: From what I can tell radio button is a part of ember.

Comment: no it is not. you must be using an addon.

Comment: I found it thanks. So this is slightly unrelated but of course I can't comment on the actual post because insanity-inducing limitations of this site.. How do you know WHAT FILE to put ANY Ember code people post. Because in every post I find, the answer says : Here's the code. NO file to put it in when Ember has controllers, views, adders, helpers, gizmos, 5000 files. I've never found any answer telling you where to put the code and yet, people are like "it works! thanks" when I try it, it never works. ever. Please help.

Comment: Instead of `class="tooltip-enhanced"`, can you try `radioClass="tooltip-enhanced"`?